# Query works in SSMS and 'Execute Query' when building a connection in Telerik, but report fails

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, telerik

**Edit:  It ended up being the report file itself.  I recreated the report file and did not experience the issues I was having. Original issue below:**

I am adding to an existing, functional report in Telerik and I am encountering the following message every time I try to run the report:

> An error has occurred while processing Table 'table 1':
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition was expected, near ','

I use a Int32 parameter to allow the user to select a report type, 0, 1, or 2 depending on which set of data they need.  0 and 1 were already in the file and working, I was attempting to add set '2'.

The query executes without issue with my changes in SSMS.  I have marked the section I added in the comments below:

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '11/19/2019';
DECLARE @ReportType INT = 2; -- 0 = All locations, 1 = Downtown, 2 = Parks
DECLARE @ViolationID INT = 0;

-- Streets are grouped by each OR clause to make future edits much easier
SELECT l.cit_loc_desc, 
    ISNULL(c.cit_block_num, '') AS [cit_block_num], 
    COUNT(c.cit_uid) AS cit_count,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(c.cit_is_void, 0) AS INT)) AS cit_is_void, 
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(c.cit_is_warning, 0) AS INT)) AS cit_is_warning,
    SUM(ISNULL(oa.cit_orig_amt, 0)) AS cit_orig_amt,
    SUM(ISNULL(lf.cit_late_fee, 0)) AS cit_late_fee,
    SUM(ISNULL(p.cit_payments, 0)) AS cit_payments,
    SUM(ISNULL(aa.cit_adj_amt, 0)) AS cit_adjustments, 
    SUM(c.cit_amount_due) AS cit_amount_due,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.cit_appealed, 0)) AS cit_appealed,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(ap.appl_is_active, 0) AS INT)) AS appl_is_active,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_req_hearing, 0)) AS appl_req_hearing,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_fine_decreased, 0)) AS appl_fine_decreased,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_found_liable, 0)) AS appl_found_liable,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_not_liable, 0)) AS appl_not_liable,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_pm_course_complete, 0)) AS appl_pm_course_complete
-- NOTE: If they come back and say that cit_meter_num is not the same as cit_block_num, just use Citations table
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cit_uid,
            cit_location,
            cit_ticket_number,
            cit_violation_date,
            cit_is_void,
            cit_is_warning,
            cit_late_fee_applied,
            cit_vio_id, 
            ISNULL(IIF(cit_block_num IS NULL, cit_meter_num, IIF(LEN(cit_block_num) = 0, cit_meter_num, cit_block_num)), '') AS cit_block_num,
            cit_amount_due
        FROM Citations) c
INNER JOIN Cit_Location_Ref l ON c.cit_location = l.cit_loc_id
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ABS(SUM(fin_trans_amount)) AS cit_payments
            FROM Financial_Transactions 
            WHERE fin_receipt_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid
                AND fin_pay_meth_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_receipt_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_pay_meth_uid <> '8AB8D29B-3818-4A41-965E-F7AFDA70111D') p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_late_fee
            FROM Financial_Transactions
            WHERE fin_trans_type_uid = 'DD1FA83F-55AF-4849-8133-C19F675085BD'
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) lf
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_orig_amt
            FROM Financial_Transactions
            WHERE fin_trans_type_uid = '849AEB50-6D94-407E-975B-9C0077EBD6E6'
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) oa
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_adj_amt
             FROM Financial_Transactions
             WHERE fin_trans_type_uid IN('9D153BA5-F654-42C6-9A64-1837E0F8F0B9', 'BDB886EF-8283-4BF1-9169-D2666F67F022')
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) aa
LEFT JOIN (SELECT acr.cit_uid,
             1 AS cit_appealed,
             IIF(a.appl_closed_date IS NULL OR a.appl_judgement_uid IS NULL, 1, 0) AS appl_is_active,
             IIF(a.appl_scheduled_hearing_date IS NULL, 0, 1) AS appl_req_hearing,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = 'AB7563CA-ABBD-42CE-8719-A010C04A3A30', 1, 0) AS appl_fine_decreased,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid IN('BEEA5FC8-2531-44DE-9A44-78B8AE741809', 'AB7563CA-ABBD-42CE-8719-A010C04A3A30',
                    '42CC9AD5-B56B-4944-9D9C-449CFEE585A6', 'E294A856-E8E8-40C2-BDAA-9CB66988CEC3'), 1, 0) AS appl_found_liable,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = '9DF8A7FB-F79E-41EB-B5B0-F06F577CF75B', 1, 0) AS appl_not_liable,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = '71238A92-C579-4F73-B8F4-8D1DD7AA3142', 1, 0) AS appl_pm_course_complete
        FROM Appeal_Citation_Rel acr
        INNER JOIN Appeals a ON acr.appl_uid = a.appl_uid
        WHERE a.appl_judgement_uid IS NULL OR a.appl_judgement_uid NOT IN('D8DA87A5-4BA5-4F09-BE76-F1AB3539A38D','2FC137F4-30C3-435C-A84F-E82A96BA6E49',
                'F6192A95-7E1F-4EC4-8A4D-E04647DEF10E','301229C0-8BCA-42CB-B7DA-A20F4DF9BD29')) ap ON c.cit_uid = ap.cit_uid
WHERE (
    @ReportType = 0 OR -- All Locations
    -- Downtown
    (@ReportType = 1 AND ((c.cit_location = 436 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%' AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3) -- 100-200 W MLK
    OR (c.cit_location = 161 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Edward Gary
    OR (c.cit_location IN(124,414,444) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 N Edward Gary
    OR (c.cit_location = 199 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W San Antonio St
    OR (c.cit_location = 438 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 E San Antonio St
    OR (c.cit_location = 57 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300- E Hopkins
    OR (c.cit_location IN(203,409,440) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W Hopkins
    OR (c.cit_location = 58 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 E Hutchison
    OR (c.cit_location IN(204,400,441) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W Hutchison
    OR (c.cit_location IN(138,407) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Pat Garrison
    OR (c.cit_location = 195 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 University Dr
    OR (c.cit_location IN(217,429) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 Concho
    OR (c.cit_location IN(200,380) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%') -- 100-200 W Woods
    OR (c.cit_location = 54 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 E Woods
    OR (c.cit_location IN(94,398) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Lindsey 
    OR (c.cit_location = 22 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Burleson
    OR (c.cit_location = 381 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Moore
    OR (c.cit_location = 130 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 North St
    OR (c.cit_location IN(123,401) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Comanche
    OR (c.cit_location = 476 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Comanche
    OR (c.cit_location = 163 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Fredericksburg
    OR (c.cit_location IN(119,408) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Fredericksburg
    OR (c.cit_location = 164 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Guadalupe
    OR (c.cit_location IN(126,411,442) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Guadalupe
    OR (c.cit_location = 165 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%') -- 100-200 S LBJ
    OR (c.cit_location IN(1,127,412,433,439) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N LBJ
    OR (c.cit_location = 160 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S CM Allen
    OR (c.cit_location IN(425,122) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[34]%')))
    -- begin additional block 
    OR ( 
            @ReportType = 2 AND ( --parks
            c.cit_location IN(4, 31, 35, 36, 103, 150, 160, 196, 224, 425, 430, 434)
            OR (c.cit_location = 3 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 24 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '6%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 31 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 32 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '5%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 33 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[89]%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 57 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[46]%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 223 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 108 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 355 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '6%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 154 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[146]%')
            OR (c.cit_location = 184 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '9%')
        )
      )
      -- end additional block
    ) 
    -- ALL OTHER CRITERIA BELOW HERE
    AND (@ViolationID = 0 OR c.cit_vio_id IN(@ViolationID))
    AND CAST(c.cit_violation_date AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY l.cit_loc_desc, c.cit_block_num
ORDER BY l.cit_loc_desc, c.cit_block_num
```

This query will also execute and return data when I execute it within **Preview Data Source Results** in Telerik:

[image: Screenshot of Preview Data Source Results, showing good data]

'table1' shows results straight from the query and doesn't do any conditional formatting.  I have also opened the report file in a text editor to see if the @ReportType parameter was somehow referenced as a boolean or BIT type since before it only had the values of 0 or 1, but I found no such reference.

Is there anything else I can look for?  I'm not seeing anything that makes sense that would explain why the report fails when inserting that other condition in the main query as above.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
I contacted the vendor and they added a custom view to the database for this piece:

```
    CASE WHEN ((c.cit_location = 436 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%' AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3) -- 100-200 W MLK
                OR (c.cit_location = 161 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Edward Gary
                OR (c.cit_location IN(124,414,444) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 N Edward Gary
                OR (c.cit_location = 199 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W San Antonio St
                OR (c.cit_location = 438 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 E San Antonio St
                OR (c.cit_location = 57 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300- E Hopkins
                OR (c.cit_location IN(203,409,440) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W Hopkins
                OR (c.cit_location = 58 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[123]%') -- 100-300 E Hutchison
                OR (c.cit_location IN(204,400,441) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 W Hutchison
                OR (c.cit_location IN(138,407) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Pat Garrison
                OR (c.cit_location = 195 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 University Dr
                OR (c.cit_location IN(217,429) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 Concho
                OR (c.cit_location IN(200,380) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%') -- 100-200 W Woods
                OR (c.cit_location = 54 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 E Woods
                OR (c.cit_location IN(94,398) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Lindsey 
                OR (c.cit_location = 22 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Burleson
                OR (c.cit_location = 381 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 Moore
                OR (c.cit_location = 130 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%') -- 100-400 North St
                OR (c.cit_location IN(123,401) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Comanche
                OR (c.cit_location = 476 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Comanche
                OR (c.cit_location = 163 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Fredericksburg
                OR (c.cit_location IN(119,408) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Fredericksburg
                OR (c.cit_location = 164 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S Guadalupe
                OR (c.cit_location IN(126,411,442) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N Guadalupe
                OR (c.cit_location = 165 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12]%') -- 100-200 S LBJ
                OR (c.cit_location IN(1,127,412,433,439) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[12345]%') -- 100-500 N LBJ
                OR (c.cit_location = 160 AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%') -- 100 S CM Allen
                OR (c.cit_location IN(425,122) AND LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[34]%')) THEN 1 --downtown
            WHEN (c.cit_location IN(4, 31, 35, 36, 103, 150, 160, 196, 224, 425, 430, 434)
                OR (c.cit_location = 3 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '1%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 24 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '6%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 31 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[1234]%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 32 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '5%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 33 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[89]%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 57 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[46]%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 223 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 108 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 355 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '6%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 154 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '[146]%')
                OR (c.cit_location = 184 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '9%')) THEN 2 --parks
            ELSE 0 END AS cit_location_code
FROM Citations c
```

Which shortened the main query significantly:

```
-- Streets are grouped by each OR clause to make future edits much easier
SELECT l.cit_loc_desc, 
    ISNULL(c.cit_block_num, '') AS [cit_block_num], 
    COUNT(c.cit_uid) AS cit_count,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(c.cit_is_void, 0) AS INT)) AS cit_is_void, 
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(c.cit_is_warning, 0) AS INT)) AS cit_is_warning,
    SUM(ISNULL(oa.cit_orig_amt, 0)) AS cit_orig_amt,
    SUM(ISNULL(lf.cit_late_fee, 0)) AS cit_late_fee,
    SUM(ISNULL(p.cit_payments, 0)) AS cit_payments,
    SUM(ISNULL(aa.cit_adj_amt, 0)) AS cit_adjustments, 
    SUM(c.cit_amount_due) AS cit_amount_due,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.cit_appealed, 0)) AS cit_appealed,
    SUM(CAST(ISNULL(ap.appl_is_active, 0) AS INT)) AS appl_is_active,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_req_hearing, 0)) AS appl_req_hearing,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_fine_decreased, 0)) AS appl_fine_decreased,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_found_liable, 0)) AS appl_found_liable,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_not_liable, 0)) AS appl_not_liable,
    SUM(ISNULL(ap.appl_pm_course_complete, 0)) AS appl_pm_course_complete
-- NOTE: If they come back and say that cit_meter_num is not the same as cit_block_num, just use Citations table
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cit_uid,
            cit_location,
            cit_ticket_number,
            cit_violation_date,
            cit_is_void,
            cit_is_warning,
            cit_late_fee_applied,
            cit_vio_id, 
            ISNULL(IIF(cit_block_num IS NULL, cit_meter_num, IIF(LEN(cit_block_num) = 0, cit_meter_num, cit_block_num)), '') AS cit_block_num,
            cit_amount_due,
            cit_location_code
        FROM Custom_Cit_With_Location_Code) c
INNER JOIN Cit_Location_Ref l ON c.cit_location = l.cit_loc_id
CROSS APPLY(SELECT ABS(SUM(fin_trans_amount)) AS cit_payments
            FROM Financial_Transactions 
            WHERE fin_receipt_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid
                AND fin_pay_meth_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_receipt_uid IS NOT NULL
                AND fin_pay_meth_uid <> '8AB8D29B-3818-4A41-965E-F7AFDA70111D') p
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_late_fee
            FROM Financial_Transactions
            WHERE fin_trans_type_uid = 'DD1FA83F-55AF-4849-8133-C19F675085BD'
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) lf
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_orig_amt
            FROM Financial_Transactions
            WHERE fin_trans_type_uid = '849AEB50-6D94-407E-975B-9C0077EBD6E6'
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) oa
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(fin_trans_amount) AS cit_adj_amt
             FROM Financial_Transactions
             WHERE fin_trans_type_uid IN('9D153BA5-F654-42C6-9A64-1837E0F8F0B9', 'BDB886EF-8283-4BF1-9169-D2666F67F022')
                AND fin_entity_cit_uid = c.cit_uid) aa
LEFT JOIN (SELECT acr.cit_uid,
             1 AS cit_appealed,
             IIF(a.appl_closed_date IS NULL OR a.appl_judgement_uid IS NULL, 1, 0) AS appl_is_active,
             IIF(a.appl_scheduled_hearing_date IS NULL, 0, 1) AS appl_req_hearing,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = 'AB7563CA-ABBD-42CE-8719-A010C04A3A30', 1, 0) AS appl_fine_decreased,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid IN('BEEA5FC8-2531-44DE-9A44-78B8AE741809', 'AB7563CA-ABBD-42CE-8719-A010C04A3A30',
                    '42CC9AD5-B56B-4944-9D9C-449CFEE585A6', 'E294A856-E8E8-40C2-BDAA-9CB66988CEC3'), 1, 0) AS appl_found_liable,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = '9DF8A7FB-F79E-41EB-B5B0-F06F577CF75B', 1, 0) AS appl_not_liable,
             IIF(a.appl_judgement_uid = '71238A92-C579-4F73-B8F4-8D1DD7AA3142', 1, 0) AS appl_pm_course_complete
        FROM Appeal_Citation_Rel acr
        INNER JOIN Appeals a ON acr.appl_uid = a.appl_uid
        WHERE a.appl_judgement_uid IS NULL OR a.appl_judgement_uid NOT IN('D8DA87A5-4BA5-4F09-BE76-F1AB3539A38D','2FC137F4-30C3-435C-A84F-E82A96BA6E49',
                'F6192A95-7E1F-4EC4-8A4D-E04647DEF10E','301229C0-8BCA-42CB-B7DA-A20F4DF9BD29')) ap ON c.cit_uid = ap.cit_uid
WHERE (@ViolationID = 0 OR c.cit_vio_id IN(@ViolationID))
    AND CAST(c.cit_violation_date AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND (@ReportType = 0 OR @ReportType = c.cit_location_code)
GROUP BY l.cit_loc_desc, c.cit_block_num
ORDER BY l.cit_loc_desc, c.cit_block_num
```

When I add this updated query to the report, I get the same error message as above, so it is not related to the length of the query.  I deleted `table1` and recreated it in Telerik with just the data, no formatting or subtotals and I still get this error message.

The only thing I haven't tried is recreating the report from scratch which is a last resort due to the time involved. Is there anything else I can try?  Thanks again.

Comment: Wow... That query could do with a huge rework... I would honestly strongly suggest moving to a dynamic approach with that statement. No cached version of the query plan is every going to be helpful to the dozens of permutations it could have. If you, for reasons unknown, must keep it as is at least use the `RECOMPILE` option. This is definitely a Kitchen Sink of Queries (as Aaron Bertrand would call them).

Comment: Agree that it needs rework. Rather than going dynamic I would work out a set of tables that contain the criteria, like ReporType, Location, CityBlockNum etc, then simply join to that in your query. It will make the addition of new criteria such as you have done trivial, instead of requiring re-coding and debugging!

Comment: Sometimes when something reports this type of error it is because the query has been truncated somewhere. I wonder if you have hit a limit to the length of the sql query allowed - is is possible to create a stored proc or view and try that instead? You could also check with the sql profiler what is actually being passed. You may find it is less than you expect.

Comment: To add evidence to this possibility - I see that your query was under 8000 characters before your edit, and over 8000 after. That is a significant length as the maximum for a varchar in SQL Server.

Comment: Unfortunately this is with a proprietary system where I do not have access to the database to create a view or stored procedure that could make this more efficient.  I will see if there is another way to shorten this query.  I hadn't considered that before but it makes sense.  Thanks everyone for your responses.

Comment: Removing all comments and white characters at beginning of line would make your query less than 8000 characters again, try this.

Comment: @HeatherM Factoring out `LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3` where applicable would be a quick change. Combining conditions like `(c.cit_location = 223 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')` and `(c.cit_location = 108 and LEN(c.cit_block_num) = 3 AND c.cit_block_num LIKE '4%')` where the `like` pattern is identical to use `c.cit_location  in ( 108, 223 ) and ...` is a little more work.

Comment: See my edits above.  I was able to get the vendor to put the location conditions in a view that cut down on the query significantly, but the same problem persists.

Comment: Try `@ReportType = CAST(0 AS INT)` in your `WHERE` clause. I've had the same problem before in SSRS.

Comment: Well, it was indeed the report file.  I recreated the report from scratch and no issues.  I appreciate everyone's advice and help.